# How to exclude certain elements from a List

Tags: java

I have a List with the following elements.

```
List<String> numbers = new ArrayList<String>();
numbers.add("1");
numbers.add("2");
numbers.add("3");
```

How do I get a subset of the List without say `"1"`? Is there a simpler function which will work against a List of any type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com) to create a filtered `Collection` view:

```
Collection<String> filtered = Collections2.filter(numbers,
    Predicates.not(Predicates.equalTo("1")));
```

That's a live view of the original `List`, so it's very efficient to create but might not be efficient to use depending on how you need to use it and how small the filtered collection is compared to the original. You can copy it to a new list if that will work better:

```
List<String> filteredList = Lists.newArrayList(filtered);
```

The simplest way to create a copy list containing all elements except the one you don't want is to use a simple `for` loop:

```
List<String> copy = new ArrayList<String>();
for (String number : numbers) {
  if (!"1".equals(number))
    copy.add(number);
}
```

If you want to modify the original list instead, `numbers.removeAll` is what you want (as mentioned by @Robin Green).

Answer (score 7):

The question is ambiguous.

`numbers.remove("1");` will remove the first instance of "1" in any list. If you might have duplicate elements, use `numbers.removeAll (Collections.singletonList ("1"));` to remove all of them.

If on the other hand you want to get a subrange of the list, use the `subList` method.

Comment: Is there a way to achieve this without modifying the original list. I am assuming you should just clone it every time you want to remove

Comment: @Joe Check out ColinD's answer. By the way, if you are really interested in functional programming (programming without destructive updates), check out Scalaz for Scala (which runs on the JVM) or Haskell (which doesn't) or F# (which runs on .NET).

Answer (score 6):

I think this could help you out:

```
final List<String> numbers = Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3");

final List<String> filtered = numbers.stream()
                                     .filter(num -> !"1".equals(num))
                                     .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 3):

you can take a look at [Guava libraries](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/) which has a filter method on any collection type.
here are [some examples](http://codemunchies.com/2009/11/functional-java-filtering-and-ordering-with-google-collections-part-3/) for your reference.

If you don't want to use third party libraries, you have to manually iterate the list and need to copy the elements which doesn't match your criteria.

Comment: Yes, that is a more general solution (to one possible interpretation of the question!), but it may be more general than what the questioner needed at this time.

Comment: yes but your answer will modify the existing list.. which might not be the requirement.

Answer (score 1):

[List.subList(int fromIndex, int toIndex)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList%28int,%20int%29)

Edit: Possible that I didn't understand the question.

@Op. Do you want to remove items of a certain value, or do you want to have a view between two indices?

Comment: I just know the value, don't have any info on the index.

Comment: Ah, ok. Do you how if the only will be one, or can there be several?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, for example to remove the `1`(s) from the list you could do:

```
int i = 0;
while((i = numbers.indexOf("1")) > -1) {
     numbers.remove(i);
}
```

You can do this with a list of objects, too, or a filtering criterion.

Edit: There will only be one and not many? Then just do:

```
int i = 0;
if((i = numbers.indexOf("1")) > -1) {
     numbers.remove(i);
}
```

Comment: That's an inefficient way of doing this since it starts iterating at the beginning of the list again each time it removes. Better would be to use the iterator and go through it once removing each match.

Answer (score 0):

From Java8 onward, stream api can be used, for example:

```
    final List<String> list = Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3", "4", "5");
    final List<String> listToExclude = Arrays.asList("2", "3");

    final List<String> filtered = list.stream()
            .filter(item -> !listToExclude.contains(item))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    System.out.println(filtered);  // returns {"1", "4", "5"}
```